# Restart node upon changing a file

Tags: node.js

For someone who is coming from PHP background the process of killing node and starting it again after every code change, seems very tedious. Is there any flag when starting a script with node to automatically restart node when code change is saved?

Comment: Funny to come back to this question almost 10 years later! I've recently authored https://github.com/gajus/turbowatch for the exact use case. It is worth noting that Node.js also has native --watch functionality as of v18 https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v18.11.0

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[forever module](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) has a concept of multiple node.js servers, and can start, restart, stop and list currently running servers. It can also watch for changing files and restart node as needed.

Install it if you don't have it already:

```
npm install forever -g
```

After installing it, call the `forever` command: use the `-w` flag to watch file for changes:

```
forever -w ./my-script.js
```

In addition, you can watch directory and ignore patterns:

```
forever --watch --watchDirectory ./path/to/dir --watchIgnore *.log ./start/file
```

Comment: +1 forever is pretty versatile for both development/testing and production.

Comment: I have tried using forever to restart my ES2015 Expess.js/Webpack server with this command  

    `forever -c babel-node -w --watchDirectory ./server ./server/index.js`

but sadly it seems to send forever into a tailspin and it restarts the server too often, resulting in port already in use errors...is there someway to add a pause after a restart?

Comment: @BrianDiPalma You should perhaps add some ignore patterns, if there are any changing files, such as logs, under the watch directory. Check the docs to see if you can define a delay between restarts.

Comment: @hyde It wasn't a delay that was required it was the `-t` or `killTree` option that was required, I guess babel-node was being killed but not the Express server it spawned.

Comment: Forever JS has a bug in Windows that doesn't kill the Node process when the script is terminated. Have to manually kill the Node process :(  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556852/how-to-stop-node-js-application-using-forever-module-on-windows

Comment: # forever start -w file.js

Answer (score 163):

A good option is [Node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor):

```
npm install supervisor -g
```

and after migrating to the root of your application use the following

```
supervisor app.js
```

Comment: same here, for whatever reason, as I used nodemon before without any issue.

Comment: Worked for me too. I had to override the default wildcard watch parameter to `server.js` because it was constantly restarting, this was due to my server building the client on boot and thus changing the files. `supervisor --watch server.js server.js` solved it.

Comment: Node-supervisor isn't maintained any more.

Comment: My favourite one, refresh intervals to check if file is modified is almost instant!

Comment: There is a bug. Add a new js file and then change an existing js file to require it. Application restarts ok. Change that last added js file and application doesn't restart.

Answer (score 126):

You should look at something like [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

Nodemon will watch the files in the directory in which nodemon was started, and if they change, it will automatically restart your node application.

Example:

```
nodemon ./server.js localhost 8080
```

or simply

```
nodemon server
```

Comment: Any idea why Node requires restart to implement code changes? And why do other servers (like Apache/PHP) don't require restart?

Comment: @dk49 because PHP scripts in that case are started for every incoming request, and stopped after they've done generating the page.

Comment: @Daerdemandt thanks for sharing that..but I still did not get why does the server (on any platform) need to start and stop? Is it because it maintains a cache of files (responses)? I thought that the server will be loading the files from disk at the time of request, process it and then send the response. I am new to server-side programming.

Comment: Can you/should you use nodemon in production environment?

Comment: Not sure how nodemon still holds up today (as this was back in 2012), but for security reasons I'm not sure I would want my server restarting on prod whenever a file changes. Something like pm2 might be more appropriate for a production environment.

Comment: @maverick "node" just runs whatever script you tell it to use, that is the expected behavior. In general, you wouldn't want your app to stop at some arbitrary point because a file changed, would be bad for security, uptime, etc. If you create a server like `php server.php` you'll see it's the same as Node, it will keep running (if you configure it right.) But Node was created from scratch to act as a server, PHP wasn't. I vaguely remember hearing Lisp can somehow recompile itself while running (disclaimer: not a Lisp dev) which made it attractive for "artificial intelligence" enthusiasts.

Answer (score 58):

Various NPM packages are available to make this task easy.

**For Development**

- [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/): most popular and actively maintained
- [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/): second-most popular
- [node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dev/): actively maintained (as of Oct 2020)
- [supervisor](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor/): no longer maintained

**For Production** (with extended functionality such as clustering, remote deploy etc.)

- [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/): `npm install -g pm2`
- [Strong Loop Process Manager](http://strong-pm.io/): `npm install -g strongloop`

Comparison between Forever, pm2 and StrongLoop can be found on [StrongLoop](http://strong-pm.io/compare/)'s website.

Comment: @2019 nodemon seems the only one of the 4 development-options that is still maintained.

Comment: @mvermand Yeah, no new releases have been released recently for either one of them except for nodemon. For production, PM2 is still well maintained.

Answer (score 22):

You can also try [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

To Install Nodemon

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

To use Nodemon

Normally we start node program like:

```
node server.js
```

But here you have to do like:

```
nodemon server.js
```

Comment: nodemon has annoying bugs. It was a time waster for me.

Comment: How is this answer any different from [the 2012 nodemon answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175772/1269037)?

Answer (score 10):

> node-dev

node-dev is great alternative to both nodemon and supervisor for developers who like to get growl (or libnotify) notifications on their desktop whenever the server **restarts** or when there is an **error** or **change** occur in file.

**Installation:**

```
npm install -g node-dev
```

*Use node-dev, instead of node:*

```
node-dev app.js
```

**Notification on Changing file so server start automatically**

[image]

**console out put**

[image]

Comment: For TypeScript users there's `ts-node-dev`

Answer (score 9):

Nodejs supports watching mode since [v18.11.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases/tag/v18.11.0). To run it just pass `--watch` argument:

`node --watch ./index.js`

Note: this is an experimental feature.

Comment: Replaced nodemon in my case. 

If needed to restart as 'rs' command do in nodemon, just save related file in the IDE (no changes needed).

Comment: For me this result in `node: bad option: --watch`

Comment: @Mitya what is the output if you run `node -v`? Do you specify file path?

Comment: @mbelsky 16.14.2. And yes, I used `node --watch ./bin/www`. In the end I just installed nodemon

Comment: @Mitya well this is the reason. `--watch` option is available only in node v18.11.0 and higher versions.

Answer (score 7):

Follow the steps:

1. `npm install --save-dev nodemon`
2. Add the following two lines to "script" section of package.json:

```
"start": "node ./bin/www",
"devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www"
```

as shown below:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

3. `npm run devstart`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website

Comment: Well, it's [essentially the same answer as the 2012 one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-a-file/58651252?noredirect=1#comment108412473_41346644), but present with more "magic" around it. But the *essence* of the answer is "use nodemon". The reset is tangential. And it was poorly formatted, but I see that David fixed that, so I'll undo my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

I use `runjs` like:

```
runjs example.js
```

The package is called just [`run`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run)

```
npm install -g run
```

Comment: it's not better, just another option

Comment: This answer would be much more valuable if it explained *why* you use `run`, and how it compared to existing alternatives. Just dumping another option only contributes to the paradox of choice. (Fortunately `run` hasn't been updated since 2015, so now it's not much of an option.)