# Restart process on file change in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a simple solution (using common shell utils, via a util provided by most distributions, or some simple python/... script) to restart a process when some files change?

It would be nice to simply call sth like `watch -cmd "./the_process -arg" deps/*`.

**Update:**
A simple shell script together with the proposed inotify-tools (nice!) fit my needs (works for commands w/o arguments):

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
  $@ &
  PID=$!
  inotifywait $1
  kill $PID
done
```

Comment: Can anybody explain what does the "$!" do please (Couldn't find it with Google), Thanks.

Comment: It returns the id of the previously started process

Comment: If a filesystem does not have the `noatime` attribute, then target script/process will be restarted in an infinite loop because of the `access` event. To fix that, use `inotifywait -e modify $1` instead, which will only react to file modification events.

Comment: For nodejs, there is a whole bunch of specific solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-a-file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can watch a directory via the *inotify* system using `inotifywait` or `inotifywatch` from the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/).

`inotifywait` will exit upon detecting an event. Pass option `-r` to watch directories recursively. Example: `inotifywait -r mydirectory`.

You can also specify the event to watch for instead of watching all events. To wait only for file or directory content changes use option `-e modify`.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Jon I've added an example for `inotifywait` which seems to be better suited for this task than `inotifywatch`.

Comment: inotify-tools don't seem to have been updated for a couple of years now. `entr` (suggested below by @matanster) looks more current and probably easier to use for the OPs case

Answer (score 21):

This is an improvement on the answer provided in the question. When one interrupts the script, the run process should be killed.

```
#!/bin/sh

sigint_handler()
{
  kill $PID
  exit
}

trap sigint_handler SIGINT

while true; do
  $@ &
  PID=$!
  inotifywait -e modify -e move -e create -e delete -e attrib -r `pwd`
  kill $PID
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Note that you have to add `-e attrib` if you want `touch somefile` to trigger a restart.

Comment: Clever! You might have to remove the SIG prefix: `trap sigint_handler INT TERM`.

Comment: I would remove `PID=$!` and replace `kill $PID` with `kill $(jobs -p)` to ensure it won't kill some other program in case the other one exited early.

Comment: @Mansour I tried that, and I like the precaution, but `jobs -p` lists stopped and running jobs, so it also will try to kill process that aren't running. I think this is a reasonably safe solution: `[[ $(jobs -pr) == "" ]] || kill $(jobs -pr)`. The `r` makes it only list running jobs, and the disjunction assures it will only run if there are actually process to kill.

Answer (score 13):

Check out [`iWatch`](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html):

> Watch is a realtime filesystem monitoring program. It is a tool for detecting changes in filesystem and reporting it immediately.It uses a simple config file in XML format and is based on inotify, a file change notification system in the Linux kernel.

than, you could watch files easily:

```
iwatch /path/to/file -c 'run_you_script.sh'
```

Comment: Maybe this is even the better answer, but I prefer the DIY solution using the inotify-tools.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but after a closer look it's not working for me. It captures one event, but then it stops working :-/

Answer (score 10):

I find that this suits the full scenario requested by the PO quite very well:

```
ls *.py | entr -r python my_main.py
```

To run in the background, you'll need the `-n` non-interactive mode.

```
ls | entr -nr go run example.go &
```

See also http://eradman.com/entrproject/, although a bit oddly documented. Yes, you need to `ls` the file pattern you want matched, and pipe that into the `entr` executable. It will run your program and rerun it when any of the matched files change.

PS: It's not doing a diff on the piped text, so you don't need anything like `ls --time-style`

Comment: it's not some kind of daemon, it's just a plain command, won't survive a reboot

Comment: for mac this is by far the simplest option if you have home-brew installed. I'm working on a cloud function (GCloud) and needed a quick way to test locally without having to constantly reload. Here's my one-liner after I installed entr (brew install entr): ls index.js|entr -r npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=helloWorld

Answer (score 1):

There's a perl script call `lrrr` (little restart runner, really) that I'm a contributor on. I use it daily at work.

You can install it with `cpanm App::lrrr` if you have a perl and cpanm installed, and then use it as follows:

```
lrrr -w dirs,or_files,to-watch your_cmd_here
```

The w flag marks off files or directories to watch. Currently, it kills the process you ran if a file is changed, but I'm gonna add a feature soon to toggle that.

Please let me know if there's anything to be added!

Answer (score 1):

I use this "one liner" to restart long-running processes based on file changes

```
trap 'kill %1' 1 2 3 6; while : ; do YOUR_EXE & inotifywait -r YOUR_WATCHED_DIRECTORY -e create,delete,modify || break; kill %1; sleep 3; done
```

This will start the process, keep its output to the same console, watch for changes, if there is one, it will shut down the process, wait three seconds (for further within-same-second writes or process shutdown times), then do the above again.
ctrl-c & ssh-disconnect will be respected and the process will exit once you're done.

For legibility:

```
trap 'kill %1' 1 2 3 6
while :
do
    YOUR_EXE &
    inotifywait \
        -r YOUR_WATCHED_DIRECTORY \
        -e create,delete,modify \
    || break
    kill %1
    sleep 3
done
```

E.g. for a package.json-ran project

```
"module"          : "./dist/server.mjs",
"scripts"         : {
    "build"  : "cd ./src && rollup -c ",
    "watch"  : "cd ./src && rollup -c -w",
    "start"  : "cd ./dist && node --trace-warnings --enable-source-maps ./server.mjs",
    "test"   : "trap 'kill %1' 1 2 3 6; while : ; do npm run start & inotifywait -r ./dist -e create,delete,modify || break; kill %1; sleep 3; done"
},
"dependencies"    : {
```

Here now you can run `npm run watch` (which compiles from src to dist) in one activity, `npm run test` (the server runner & restarter) in another, and as you edit `./src` files the builder process will update `./dist` and the server will restart for you to test.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution for golang's `go run` command which spawns a subprocess.  So combining the answers above and [pidtree](https://superuser.com/a/784102/524394) gave me this script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# go file to run
MAIN=cmd/example/main.go

# directories to recursively monitor
DIRS="cmd pkg"

# Based on pidtree from https://superuser.com/a/784102/524394
pidtree() {
  declare -A CHILDS
  while read P PP; do
    CHILDS[$PP]+=" $P"
  done < <(ps -e -o pid= -o ppid=)

  walk() {
    echo $1
    for i in ${CHILDS[$1]}; do
      walk $i
    done
  }

  for i in "$@"; do
    walk $i
  done
}

sigint_handler()
{
  kill $(pidtree $PID)
  exit
}

trap sigint_handler SIGINT

while true; do
  go run $MAIN &
  PID=$!
  inotifywait -e modify -e move -e create -e delete -e attrib -r $DIRS
  
  PIDS=$(pidtree $PID)
  kill $PIDS

  wait $PID
  sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

### `-m` switch of `inotifywait` tool

As no answer here address -m switch of inotifywait tool, I will share this: **think parallel**!

How I do this:

- If I want to trig when a file is modified, I will use `CLOSE-WRITE` event.
- Instead on `while true` I use `-m` switch of `inotifywait` command.
- As many editors write on new file then rename file, I watch for **directory** instead and wait for an event with correct filename.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

cmdFile="$1"

tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
notif="$tempdir/notif"
mkfifo "$notif"

inotifywait -me close_write "${cmdFile%/*}" >"$notif" 2>&1 &
notpid=$!

exec 5<"$notif"
rm "$notif"
rmdir "$tempdir"

"$@" & cmdPid=$!

trap "kill $notpid \$cmdPid; exit" 0 1 2 3 6 9 15

while read dir evt file <&5;do
    case $file in
        ${cmdFile##*/} )
            date +"%a %d %b %T  file '$file' modified."
            kill $cmdPid
            "$@" & cmdPid=$!
            ;;
    esac
done
```