# How to completely exit a running asyncio script in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm working on a server bot in python3 (using `asyncio`), and I would like to incorporate an update function for collaborators to instantly test their contributions. It is hosted on a VPS that I access via ssh. I run the process in tmux and it is often difficult for other contributors to relaunch the script once they have made a commit, etc. I'm very new to python, and I just use what I can find. So far I have used `subprocess.Popen` to run git pull, but I have no way for it to automatically restart the script.

Is there any way to terminate a running `asyncio` loop (ideally without errors) and restart it again?

Answer (score 1):

You can not start a event loop stopped by event_loop.stop()
And in order to incorporate the changes you have to restart the script anyways (some methods might not exist on the objects you have, etc.)

I would recommend something like:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(git_tracker)
async def git_tracker():
    # check for changes in version control, maybe wait for a sync point and then:
    sys.exit(0)
```

This raises SystemExit, but despite that exits the program cleanly.
And around the `python $file.py` a `while true; do git pull && python $file.py ; done`

This is (as far as I know) the simplest approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, to stay on the safe side, you would probably need to kill the process and relaunch it.

See also: [Restart process on file change in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264238/restart-process-on-file-change-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

As a necromancer, I thought I give an up-to-date solution which we use in our UNIX system.

Using the [os.execl](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.execl) function you can tell python to replace the current process with a new one:

> These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current process; they do not return. On Unix, the new executable is loaded into the current process, and will have the same process id as the caller. Errors will be reported as OSError exceptions.

In our case, we have a bash script which executes the `killall python3.7`, sending the SIGTERM signal to our python apps which in turn listen to it via the [signal](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/signal.html#signal.signal) module and gracefully shutdown:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)
sys.exit(0)
```

The script than starts the apps in background and finishes.

> Note that `killall python3.7` will send `SIGTERM` signal to every python3.7 process!

When we need to restart we jus rune the following command:

```
os.execl("./restart.sh", 'restart.sh')
```

The first parameter is the path to the file and the second is the name of the process.