# Node.js Server Start and Stop

Tags: node.js

I am starting to learn Node.js and one of the annoying things I am encountering is the starting and stopping of the server when I make a small change to the .js file. Any alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restart node upon changing its file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-its-file)

Comment: Are you asking for automatic restart (see linked duplicate), or are you asking how to avoid restart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try installing

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

And then you run your server

```
nodemon server.js localhost 8080
```

That automatically makes you restart the server every time you save new changes

More Info. [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

Comment: It gets even easier if you also add the file as the value for the `main` entry entry in your `package.json`. Then you can just run `nodemon` and it knows which file to start. "_If no script is given, nodemon will test for a package.json file and if found, will run the file associated with the main property (ref)._" [docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

Answer (score 1):

Use something that watches for file changes and automatically restarts node.  [nodemon](https://npmjs.org/package/nodemon) is a good choice.

```
$ sudo npm install -g nodemon
$ nodemon app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

[server.close](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#server.close)

Do not call close before the "listening" event fires.

Either add a callback to listen or add an event manually

```
server.listen(port, host, function () { server.close(); });
// OR
server.on("listening", function () { server.close(); });
server.listen(port, host);

var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', console.log);
    server.close();
});

server.listen(32323);

var socket = net.createConnection(32323);
// call end to make sure the socket closes
socket.end('hi');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are nice pre-build modules that can do this for you. Check out `nodemon`, for example -- install it with npm: `npm install -g nodemon`

Instead of running `node app.js` you run `nodemon app.js`; it will automatically restart your application whenever you make a change.