# Reloading Connect/Express server code using grunt-contrib-watch and reload option

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I need to make sure the server instance always runs the latest code.
Grunt-contrib-watch does reload the watched files, but the server process isn't restarted with the new code, thus old behaviour is still online, new code i.

This Grunt task [blai/grunt-express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express) does appear to contain this feature: 
**[serverreload](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express#serverreload)**

> Setting this option to true will tell express task to start a forever
>   running server in a child process, and if any of your server scripts
>   change, the server will be restarted (using a dynamically generated
>   watch task)

**UPDATE**: Tried the serverreload option in grunt-express - it doesn't appear to do what I understood, it does not change the **running server's code**

Any chance to achieve the same feature with [gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) and [gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)?

Example: starting my server from the watch 'tasks' option does run my newest code, but this doesn't appear to be a valid answer (server does not respond to HTTP requests anymore). See my [grunt connect gist](https://gist.github.com/bogdanbiv/9904709ed9370063464b) for more details.

Comment: It appears that my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-its-file. I need to check if their solution works for my problem. Indeed, when the files are changed, supervizor does restart the server (stops the server, reloads the new node module and starts the new server).

Comment: **UPDATE**:  duplicated question is two years old, I still hope there are some other (new) answers.