# How to restart node server on file change

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm developing a node/express app

```
$> ./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js index.js
```

Now I would like to reload the application if I make changes to `index.js` or any other dependency. How can I do this. I guess I have to use `gulp` for this, but than still I would like to have some advice on how to do this (which modules to use ect)

UPDATE: I've just tested with `supervisor`, but when something changes I get the following error:

```
$> /node_modules/.bin/supervisor --exec ./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js index.js 

crashing child
Starting child process with './node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js     index.js'
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1146:14)
    at listen (net.js:1172:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1257:5)
```

UPDATE: I just tried `nodemon` but I get the same errors as with `supervisor`:

```
$> nodemon  --exec ./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js index.js  --watch libs

...
22 Aug 16:58:35 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
22 Aug 16:58:35 - [nodemon] starting `./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-   node.js index.js`
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1146:14)
    at listen (net.js:1172:10)
```

UPDATE: I've solved the `EADDRINUSE` issue by adding the following to `index.js`

```
process.on('exit', () => {
    server.close();
})

process.on('uncaughtException', () => {
    server.close();

})

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    server.close();
})
```

However, now it seems to restart, but the new code is not loaded

Comment: https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: You can use nodemon - https://github.com/remy/nodemon or forever - https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Answer (score 7):

use this:

```
supervisor -- -r 'babel/register' index.js
```

and remove `server.close` code.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '/home/xavier/Documents/src/projects/sloppy/backend/babel/register'. Also tried babel-register and in both trials I have installed babel-register. `./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --version` is `5.8.34`

Comment: Update: it does work for me. Thanks. Everyone that had the same problem as I did, note the new command doesn't use `-x babel-node` anymore, but `node`.

Comment: Adding some useful supervisor options: `supervisor -n exit -e js,json -i node_modules,test -- -r 'babel/register' index.js`

Comment: With `node` version `5.5.0` and `babel-register` version `6.5.2` I had to require it as `babel-register` so: `supervisor -- -r 'babel-register' index.js`

Answer (score 3):

I was really disappointed with the performance of all the solutions where you run `babel-node` within `nodemon` (or `supervisor`). So I built this:

https://github.com/kmagiera/babel-watch

You can use it as follows (perhaps in your `package.json` scripts section):

```
babel-watch -w src src/main.js
```

The difference is that instead of restarting whole `babel-node` process on every file change (which takes like 1.5sec on my MBP) it runs `babel` in parent process and starts "pure" `node` process with all transpiled JS files provided at your script startup.

Answer (score 2):

Use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon):

**Install it globally:**

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

**Use it on your project:**

```
nodemon myscript.js
```

It will watch for changes in your project directory and restart the script when it sees them.

Comment: I've updated my post with the the errors I get when using `nodemon`. Any suggestions how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tools to do this. Take a look at this post:
[Restart node upon changing a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-a-file)

Maby the most common is Supervisor:
https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor

Comment: I've updated my post with `supervision`. Do you have any ideas why I get these `EADDRINUSE` errors ?

Answer (score 1):

The most popular tools for that purpose are [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) and [supervisor](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor). You can install them via npm. For other tasks like css pre-processors, minification, tests run etc. You can use task managers like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

use this `supervisor -- -r 'babel-register' index.js` because `Error: Cannot find module 'babel/re‌​gister'.` after checked the modules ,i thought it changed to `babel-register`   and it works for me