# Docker node express volume changes in the host not reflected in the container

Tags: node.js, express, docker

I have simple express app that I created in my host and mount with volume to the running container:

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -v $(pwd):/www -w "/www" node
```

When I change my code in the host and refresh the web page, the changes not reflected in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version and flavor (docker machine, docker for mac, docker for windows, native docker on linux) are you using? What IDE/editor are you using?

Comment: docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87, docker for mac and Atom

Comment: docker-machine 0.6.0 is from February, you could try upgrading to the latest (0.8.1 - Aug '16) via Docker Toolbox. If you have both docker-machine and docker for mac, be sure to check which you're acting using in your shell's session so you're using the intended one. `env | grep -i docker`...if you see `DOCKER_HOST` defined it should be using docker-machine.

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm restarting my container, at the beginning I run "node .", and still if the code is just overwritten, it doesn't recognize the change, only if I delete-restart-copy new-restart

Answer (score 1):

The node process needs to be restarted every time you change files for them to take effect, your volume mount is correct.

Execute this to enter your container:

```
docker exec -ti <your-container-name> /bin/bash
```

and then navigate to your files (cd /www) - You should see the file changes reflected inside of the container.

Consider using a library like [forever.js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) from inside your container to automatically refresh your server on code-changes.

( [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-a-file) helps explore the forever.js option )

Comment: I did what u suggest and I see the changes in the files but this is not reflected in the browser and I'm using nodemon by the way

Comment: That's good, so the volume mount is working - but the browser isn't reflecting changes. Are you sure nodemon is restarting your express process?

Comment: I am in attached mode, and it seems like nothing happens in the container when I change the code. ( like there is no communication )

Comment: but when you change the code, the file inside the container reflects those changes? This sounds like a nodemon problem to me

Comment: But I am changing only the templates files, and that does not need a restart of the server. When I am running the same thing in my localhost, it works fine even without nodemon

Comment: Well at this point my only further advice is to try having nodemon watch those template files for changes as well. good luck.

Comment: Thanks for you time