# Why server restart is needed in Node.Js for every change?

Tags: node.js

I am very new in Node.Js. I just started node.js basic tutorial. But when I change my code I have to restart the server all the times. But is there any way where no need to restart the server again and again.

Comment: i mean, yeah, maybe, might be possible to have the server set up in such a way that it re-reads the files to find changes, but... yeah that's probably not a good idea. But you can use tooling to make that part automatic so that when a file does change, it restarts for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart node upon changing a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [node-supervisor](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor) to restart automatically your server when you change the code.

Answer (score 2):

**Nodemon** is the best solution for this.
Install nodemon like this "npm i nodemon"
Then restart your project with nodemon, "nodemon app"
You are good to go...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on the details of the compilation process. But I think it's correct to say that on app start, your source code is parsed into computer instructions represented in memory and executed. During runtime source code files are not re-parsed. And so changing the source code will have no effect on the running application. Unless the application re-parses a file prior to execution of the code in that file. Possibly a service worker... But I'm not sure and that would be an exception.

A good way of thinking of nodejs and javascript files (imo) is that the javascript files are configuration for nodejs. Which is a c++ app. So if the configuration changes you need to restart node to read the new configuration.

There are tools such as nodemon that will monitor the source code for file saves and trigger the node application to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

> nodemon will watch the files in the directory in which nodemon was started, and if any files change, nodemon will automatically restart your node application.
>
> nodemon does not require any changes to your code or method of development. nodemon simply wraps your node application and keeps an eye on any files that have changed. Remember that nodemon is a replacement wrapper for node, think of it as replacing the word "node" on the command line when you run your script.

Comment: I guess [he just likes downvoting answers without an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b).