# Sails.js - Models & Controllers not working or throwing unexpected errors

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I'm quite new to Sails.js, but not new to MVC. I feel like I'm really close, but just missing something somewhere.

I generated a controller with a single action "overview", and if I keep it "hello world"- easy, it works. The below code runs just fine:

```
// My controller
module.exports = {
    overview : function(req, res) {     
        return res.send("<h1>Tossel<h1>");
    },
}
```

However, when I try to get some data from the model and pass it to the controller, I have issues. I've tried it in two ways. I first defined a custom method on the Model and called it from my controller, like below:

```
// My model, e.g. Orders
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'Orders',
    attributes: {
        id : {
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true
        },
        client_id : {
            type: 'integer'
        }
    },

    getAllOrders: function(opts, cb) {
        Orders.find().exec(function(err, data) {
            cb(err, data);
        });
    }
};

// My controller
module.exports = {
    overview : function(req, res) {     
        Orders. getAllOrders(null, function(err, data) {
            return res.send(data);
        });
    },
}
```

From what I can see in the docs, that's pretty much how I should do it. I get the below error though. I get this when executing the command in the console, and by calling it from the controller:

```
TypeError: query.exec is not a function
```

I then tried doing everything in the controller:

```
// My controller
module.exports = {
    overview : function(req, res) {     
        Orders.find().exec(function(err, data) {
            return res.send(data);
        });
    },
}
```

This method didn't actually throw any errors, but it returned nothing. I'm pretty sure there is data in the database though. Since I wasn't 100% sure, I created an "add" action to the controller as below, to add data to the table. This results in no errors, but the page just hangs.

```
module.exports = {
    overview : function(req, res) {     
        Orders.find().exec(function (err, data) {
            return res.json(data);
        });
    },
    add : function(req, res) {      
        var data = {
            id: 1,
            client_id: 1,
        };
        Orders.create(data).exec(function (err, data) {
            return res.send(data);
        });
    }
};
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction here. I find the docs to be too simplistic. It's good at showing you the easy stuff, but that's all it shows.

Also, as a bonus, can someone please tell me what I need to do to be able to make changes and refresh the page to see them? At the moment I have to kill the server and bring it back up again to see the changes. This doesn't seem right, I'm must be missing something somewhere.

**Edit**

As per the below comment:

- Node v8.10.0
- Sails v0.12.14
- I specify the table name because it is indeed different from the model name. I changed the actual name of the table and model in the code I posted.

Comment: First of all, you are not specifying the version of sails you use, nor the node version. Also, use console.log() or similar to see what is going on and debug where your page "hangs". Also, for your index there is no point to specify it since it is generated automatically, and I don't see where you are specifying an auto increment property. Table name should be specified if it is different from the name of your model. To make the server restart automatically upon changes, you have to use some monitoring tool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-a-file

Comment: @logout Added the info you asked about.

Comment: OK, I see you are using the old version of sails. Any particular reason to do that? 1.0 is in pre-release and I strongly recommend you using the new version. Everything for v1.0 is at https://next.sailsjs.com/ The only thing wrong I can think of is mixing different versions of sails and waterline/db adapter. Have you updated any package manually?

Comment: @logout The only reason why I'm using that version is because that's what I got when I downloaded it via npm. I haven't updated any packages manually, no. I did install an adapter for waterline though. I am playing around with Amazon's DynamoDB downloadable version, so I had to install the adapter for that.

Comment: OK. I would suggest you to try mysql or mongodb adapter just for testing purpose. If it works, then you know where your problem is.
EDIT: This is from the docs: _Note: This adapter support the Sails.js v0.10.x. check 0.9 branch if you use before v0.10
I think this adapter might not work with sails v0.12.x Maybe there is the issue.