# Is there a way to watch file changes in main js file runned in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch

There is a main.js javascript file with programm.

I run it:

> node --inspect-brk index.js

Every time when I change something in this file I have to rerun it.

I need some way to let nodejs know that this main.js file was changed and make nodejs rerun it.

Is there a way to watch file changes in main js file runned in nodejs?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart node upon changing a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175676/restart-node-upon-changing-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon). It will detect any changes to your directory and rerun the app.

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
nodemon --inspect-brk index.js
```